# Get weird number in array when use image to test my trained model

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I trained a model with 7 classees like cars,dogs,human....

when i trained it with acccuracy about 96% so
i save model with `model.save('trained-model')`

and i use this code to test model

```
    import cv2
    from keras.models import load_model
    import tensorflow as tf

    CATEGORIES=['CARS','CATS','DOGS','FLOWERS','HUMAN','MOTOBIKE','PHONES']
    def prepare(filepath):
       IMG_SIZE=256
       img_array=cv2.imread(filepath)
       new_array= cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
        return new_array.reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)
    model=tf.keras.models.load_model('trained-model',compile=False)

    predic=model.predict([prepare('dog.jpg')])
    print(predic)
```

but it print

```
[[3.4872284e-03 2.5305278e-09 9.6588148e-05 3.4947725e-04 3.5190012e-02
  9.4289863e-01 9.8522018e-05]]
```

why i have this, and how to fix this, thank you guy a lot, its about problem when trainning or something? please help

Comment: This question has been asked many times before, a simple search in this website might give you the answer, try it before asking a question.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong, did you see the question I linked?

Comment: as i know this is ratio of what in that picture, right? but i don't know why "cars" have 10^-3

Comment: yes, but, i mean, it predict ratio of dog lower than car, that mean my model have problem, right, beacause i have mre than 96% accuracy

Comment: It just means the model misclassified, having 96% accuracy does not mean the model will not make misclassifications